# bash sort a list starting at the end of each line

Tags: bash, sorting, filelist

I have a file containing file paths and filenames that I want to sort starting at the end of the string.

My file contains a list such as below:

```
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-08-12_Andrew_PC/DOCS/3177109.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-09-17_Andrew_PC/DOCS/2130419.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Bill/2016-03-17_Bill_PC/DOCS/1998816.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Charlie/2016-07-06_Charlie_PC/DOCS/4744123.doc
```

I want to sort this list such that the filenames will be sequential, this will help find duplicates based on filename regardless of path.

The list should appear like this:

```
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Bill/2016-03-17_Bill_PC/DOCS/1998816.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-09-17_Andrew_PC/DOCS/2130419.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-08-12_Andrew_PC/DOCS/3177109.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Charlie/2015-07-06_Charlie_PC/DOCS/4744128.doc
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: if your end goal is to find duplicates, it can be done without having to sort

Comment: It's often an idea to check for duplicate files by generating an MD5 checksum for each and running them through `sort | uniq -d` to find duplicate content regardless of filename.

Comment: In most operations I use sort | uniq -d but that wouldn't arrange the list so that the filename portion is the principle item sorted.  By having filenames as the principle element of the sort I can spot that we have a duplicate filenames across multiple Workers.  The goal being a folder tree free of any duplicate filenames regardless of path.  MD5 calculation could take a while for 90,000+ files.  I originally tried using awk and grep.  Awk did not like the large file list.

Comment: `Awk did not like the large file list` - That cannot be the reason as `awk` can work with really big files. It might be that you are storing the whole file data in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do this:

```
sed -e 's|^.*/\(.*\)$|\1\t\0|' list.txt | sort | cut -f 2-
```

This uses `sed` to insert a copy of the filename to the beginning of each line so that we can sort the list with `sort`. Then we remove the stuff that we added in the first step.

Comment: No disrespect, but why do you answer questions without verifying the author's attempts? Its just providing free-code without pay basically.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks very much!

Comment: @Inian: We're providing free code and advice for free, regardless of how much effort the OP puts into things. At least, I don't recall ever being paid even when the author posted his attempts.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sort -t/ -k7 input_file
```

Comment: Only if all of the paths have the same number of segments. That's going to fail horribly if you run into `/Volumes/Location/Jim/2016-09-23_Jim_PC/DOCS/Personal/1234.doc`. It works on the OP's posted sample data, but it's not a good general solution.

Comment: @JimMischel: OP didn't ask for a general solution. I prefer to follow [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 1):

This will sort based on dynamic last field which is separated by `/`. 
 First it will append last field to the start of the line and then `sort`. First field which is appended earlier is removed by second `awk`.

```
awk -F'/' '{ $0= $NF " " $0;print $0 |"sort -k1"}' fil  |awk '{print $2}'
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Bill/2016-03-17_Bill_PC/DOCS/1998816.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-09-17_Andrew_PC/DOCS/2130419.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Andrew/2015-08-12_Andrew_PC/DOCS/3177109.doc
/Volumes/Location/Workers/Charlie/2016-07-06_Charlie_PC/DOCS/4744123.doc
```